# In HTML, How to get a variable value from a JavaScript source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of the variable named "placeholder" that is set in [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.js) js file, line 740 to 743.

The file is called via a `<script>` tag in my html file, and I need th retrieve the value just after it, like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script>
\\ HERE
</script>
```

I already tried to declare a variable named "placeHold" at the top of the `intlTelInput.js` file, thinking that It would be global, but then if I do `alert(placeHold)` in my Html file, nothing is diplayed.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because I want to use the placeholder set by `intlTelInput` library in order to have a specific masked input for each number phone pattern. I want to "create" a combination of both `intlTelInput` plugin and `jQuery Mask Plugin`

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding but I'm pretty sure you don't want to try to do this.

Comment: You can't place JavaScript variables directly into your HTML. You probably need to set a class name or id on your element and use jQuery or document.querySelectorAll so you can modify the placeholder of the element.

Comment: @dlsso I forgot to put a `<script>` tag, off course what I need is to get the value on the script part of my code just after the call of the `intlTelInput.js`

Comment: @1252748 Ok to explain more clearly, I want the user to select a phone pattern with a flag selector (as with `intlTelInput`) and at the same time to "force" the input to be formated according to the pattern suggested by  `intlTelInput` (see JQuery Mask Plugin).

Comment: I suggest you read the docs for `intlTelInput` more carefully. There may be an option to do that already. Otherwise, as Will suggests you can get the placeholder by just reading it from the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin places the placeholder into the DOM. Fetch the value back out after it has done its work.

```js
$("#phone").intlTelInput();
console.log($("#phone").attr('placeholder'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>

<input id="phone" type="tel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stating what you already know here, but the value of `placeholder` is being used to set the placeholder attribute of the `telInput` element. If you're using the intlTelInput.js script to generate or manage the input element in question, it should be fairly straight forward to retrieve the placeholder value, assuming the intlTelInput.js script has already populated it:

```
var placeHold = document.querySelector(".some_tel_input").getAttribute("placeholder");
```